# Links showing on mobile menu when they should not, on active and hover

Tags: html, css, menu, nav

I have a website and the active and hover links are showing on the mobile menu when they should not. So it is like they are there all the time. 
             ```

```
html, body 
{
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto; margin: 0;
 }

 .nav {
  background-color: #3333FF;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 40px; 
  line-height: 40px;
}

.menu {
  font-family: Monserrat, sans-serif; 
  font-size: 18px; 
  color: white; 
  list-style-type: none; 
  padding: 0; 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu a {
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: #fff; 
}

.menu ul li {
  text-align: center; 
  display: inline; 
  padding: 8px; 
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px; 
  width: 24.11%;
}

.menu li:visited, .menu li:active, .active, .menu li:hover 
{
  background: #0000EE; 
  color: #fff;
}

label {
  margin: 0 14px 0 0; 
  font-size: 18px; 
  display: none;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

/* Show Hamburger */
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  label {
    cursor: pointer; 
    display: block; 
    color: #fff;
  }

  .menu {
    text-align: center; 
    width: 100%; 
    display: none;
  }

  .menu a {
    display: block; 
    background-color: #3333FF;
    margin-bottom:-40px; 
    padding: 0;
  }
  .menu li a {border-top: 1px solid #F4F4F4;}

.menu li a:active, .menu li a:hover; .menu li a:link {color: #fff; background: 0; display: none;}

  #toggle:checked + .menu {
    display: block;
  }
}



<div class="nav"><label for="toggle">&#9776;</label> <input 
     id="toggle" type="checkbox" /> <div class="menu"><ul><li><a 
     href="http://index.html">Home</a></li><li><a 
     href="http://news.html">News</a></li><li class="active"><a 
     href="http://contact.html">Contacts</a></li><li><a 
     href="http://policies.html">Policies</a></li><li><a 
     href="http://members.html">Members</a></li><li><a 
     href="http://volunteer.html">Volunteer</a></li><li><a 
     href="http://links.html">Links</a></li></ul></div>
```

Does anyone know why it is doing this as it is a mystery to me. Tried most things. I placed a active hover display none but it is still showing like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

try to use
opacity: 0;
visibility:hidden;
too